# How are Selenium automation tests actually setup to run in company following an agile software process?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests

I have just started learning about test automation in Selenium and found out that most online tutorials would tell you to run the test suite inside an IDE together with a test framework such as TestNG (with testng.xml) and a build tool such as Maven.

When you are working in a software company and told to build a test framework and run automated tests, I don't believe you actually need to fire up your IDE every time you want to execute your test suite. So, my question is, what is the typical setup a software company follows to 'automate' running your test automation scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Software companies are following agile practices and wanna keep up with industry practices. In real projects, CI & CD are used to continuously integrate, deploy and test the software.

Tests are written by SDET using test automation frameworks. While developing test scripts test developers use IDEs like eclipse. However, tests are executed over Jenkins as a job, after required frequency/event.

For example, after every code deployment, Jenkins can automatically trigger your sanity suite, and run regression bi-weekly.

The process' are automated now-a-days with stakeholders demanding agility.

One can invoke selenium java project from command line via .bat file in Jenkins, or using ant/maven as build tools.

IDEs are seldom used to run tests in real world.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I think I understand the flow now. So, an automation script developer can just keep pushing / uploading new scripts to a repository/directory which a jenkins job can then call so that it can execute these new scripts. If I understand correctly, the automation tester can just modify his test suite configuration (xml) without the need to reconfigure the jenkins job, because it calls the same .bat file (where the test suite xml is defined) every time.

Comment: Jenkins should indeed pull the scripts from your Version Control Software (VCS) at run time. If it's setup to always pick the latest version, then no configuration is needed. If it's setup to use a specific revision/version, then of course Jenkins requires an update in it's configuration as well.

Comment: @A.Kootstra - Correct. Jenkins pulls scripts, automation framework code, env. config etc. from source code repository like SVN, GIT or others.

Comment: @jeffsia- Jenkins job config is a one time activity till we need modifications in way we execute automated tests. It is immune from any changes dev do to test scripts and/or to automation framework code. Each dev can upload and commit there work to SVN without any dependency, Jenkins handles the rest.